# Autoscaling for azure cloud service not working

Tags: windows, azure, service, cloud, autoscaling

As the new autoscaling functionality became available in windows azure a few weeks ago i enabled this on my service and everything was great.

Then I deleted the deployment and deployed it again. And now I get an error saying that "Autoscale failed for [role name]" and I can only manually scale it.

I also tried deleting the service alltogether and recreate it from cratch with no improvments. This is the only service that I have this problem with and if I deploy the same solution to Another service it works.

Does anyone know how to get around this?